# Is it possible to overcome "too many requests" error creating a loop using gs_read function?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using `googlesheets` package in order for me to work with some spreadsheets and I'm facing the following small problem:

Firstly, I'm downloading the document:

```
   spreadsheet <- gs_title("Spreadsheet")
```

Ok, then I'm getting (or trying to) each one of the worksheets

```
a <- gs_read(spreadsheet, ws = "a")
b <- gs_read(spreadsheet, ws = "b")
c <- gs_read(spreadsheet, ws = "c")
d <- gs_read(spreadsheet, ws = "d")
e <- gs_read(spreadsheet, ws = "e")
```

When I'm trying to do this it happens recurrently the following:

1. no problems to read the first worksheets (normally "a" and "b")
2. when it's time to read "c" it returns the following error

   Accessing worksheet titled 'c'.
   Downloading: 1.1 kB     Error in function_list[k] : 
   Too Many Requests (RFC 6585) (HTTP 429).
3. By now I'm overcoming this in the simplest way: retrying as many times as needed until it reads the troublesome worksheets.

I've been wondering if it's possible to create a loop in order for me to make RStudio try and retry applying `gs_read` function until I get my desired outcome instead of myself doing manually the same as it's currently happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `tryCatch`

```r
read_spreadsheet <- function(spreadsheet, ws) {
  tryCatch(
    gs_read(spreadsheet, ws = ws),
    warning = function(war) {
      message(war)
      return(NULL)
    },
    error = function(err) {
      message(err)
      return(NULL)
    }
  )
}
```

Then write your loop, e.g.

```r
repeat {
  file <- read_spreadsheet(spreadsheet, ws = "a")
  if(!is.null(file)) break
}
```

(Though you need to be very sure that it will work, otherwise `repeat` won't stop)

**Edit: Warning handler**

To obtain the output despite warnings, repeat the function in the warning section:
(If you want to, you can also add suppressWarnings, warnings will be provided through message here)

```r
read_spreadsheet <- function(spreadsheet, ws) {
  tryCatch(
    gs_read(spreadsheet, ws = ws),
    warning = function(war) {
      message(war)
      return(
        suppressWarnings(gs_read(spreadsheet, ws = ws))
      )
    },
    error = function(err) {
      message(err)
      return(NULL)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas,
First of all thank you very much for your answer. I've tried with your solution and at the beginning it worked partially: it did read each worksheet, but not exactly as gs_read by itself does (actually it didn't parse anything). Then, just trying randomly, I removed from read_spreadsheets function the warning function and it started to read each worksheet exactly as I wanted it to do.
Thanks again for your solution and hope my feedback could be also useful for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I posted an update. Seems like it didn't parse your file as `return(NULL)` in the warning section prevend to go on in case of a warning. Removing the `warning` is an option though try my updated version. This handles the warning by repeating the function and evaluates the warning as a message. You could then trace back the warning and build a more detailed warning handler.